# samba-tool used to link a gpo to an ou

Tags: samba4

I have an ubuntu 22.04 server set up as an ADC to server 8 windows10 clients. It is called Server02.shop02.wood.store.
I have gpos to control the clients
Typical gpo in Group Policy Objects is "Blue screen GPO"
if I run samba-tool gpo list manager I see the Blue Screen GPO has been applied to the manager's account.
I am trying to automate the linkage of various gpos to Various OUs with Samba-tool
here is a snippet of the bash script I am trying to use for this:
`MyOU="Wood Yard Users OU" MyGPO="Blue Screen GPO" DomainName="SHOP02" samba-tool gpo setlink OU="$MyOU","DC=$DomainName,"DC=UNCLE,DC=SAMS" $"{MyGPO}"`
If anyone can point me in the correct direction I would be very grateful.